# Unable to store/retreive the value of an inherited attribute

Tags: storage, inheritance

Contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Base {
    uint stored;
    function set (uint _stored) {
        stored = _stored;
    }
    function get () constant returns (uint) {
        return stored;
    }
}

contract Child {
    Base b;
    function set (uint _stored) {
        b.set(_stored);
    }
    function get () constant returns (uint) {
        return b.get();
    }
}
```

Deployed as:

```
var i_sol_baseContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_stored","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]);
var i_sol_base = i_sol_baseContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '0x6060604052341561000c57fe5b5b60c68061001b6000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff16806360fe47b11460445780636d4ce63c146061575bfe5b3415604b57fe5b605f60048080359060200190919050506084565b005b3415606857fe5b606e608f565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b806000819055505b50565b600060005490505b905600a165627a7a72305820bcd4b3fa50cc6fc6b02c37155d3b2a414e76e8e152dc32cb9d7b75e06e5dfca60029', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })

var i_sol_childContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_stored","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]);
var i_sol_child = i_sol_childContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

Setting and getting the value works when I call `set` and `get` on the base contract. However, `get` from the `Child` always returns `0`. What is wrong in this situation?

Output from geth:

```
> i_sol_base.set(100, {from: eth.coinbase})
"0x4b35370e66082ec3eb88af8aa4c8bce64a9149daa479fdd17256b2208bd9a90a"
> i_sol_base.get()
100
> i_sol_child.set(200, {from: eth.coinbase})
"0xb9e8464468dfed83fd6d3f369bae229cf4e06de892e30f39080340c3247da777"
> i_sol_child.get()
0
> i_sol_child.get({from: eth.coinbase})
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the deployment side of this but I found issues with the contract. Corrected and tested with Remix.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Base {
    uint stored;
    function set (uint _stored) {
        stored = _stored;
    }
    function get () constant returns (uint) {
        return stored;
    }
}

contract Child {

    // this describes the ABI for Base above ^
    // but it is silent on deployed address.

    Base b;

    // This constructor will run once. Child needs a hint
    // about where it can find a deployed Base to talk to. 

    function Child(address bAddress) {
        b = Base(bAddress);
    }

    function set (uint _stored) {
        b.set(_stored);
    }

    // need to return what was received (or else default 0)

    function get () constant returns (uint) {
        return b.get();
    }
}
```

In Remix to show it working.

[image]

1. Deploy Base.
2. Copy Base Address.
3. Deploy Child and pass in Base Address.
4. Set
5. Get
6. Ta Da :-)
7. You have a known-good contract to work with as you work out the JS side.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In this case the child contract is modifying data stored in the base contract itself right? So if there are two child contracts `c1` and `c2` both of them would be modifying the same `stored`. I am trying to use inheritance the way it is typically used in OOP. So `c1.stored` would be different from `c2.stored`. Isn't this possible in solidity?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. Currently structured so Base is a storage contract. For inheritance and separate storage you might be looking for `contract Child is Base {}` Some refactoring I think as it's a non-trivial change. Child would inherit Base's storage *definition* and functions; a completely different arrangement. Each Child would have separate storage.

Comment: Gotcha! I mixed two different concepts and ended up with that. Thanks a lot :)